# Rollback protection for network booting

Tags: pxe, secure-boot

I am interested in secure network booting.  UEFI Secure Boot, combined with a signing key I control, ensures that no unauthorized code can run.  However, it doesn’t provide rollback protection: an attacker can cause an earlier version of the OS to run.

Is there a way to prevent this? The first one that comes to mind is:

- The initramfs compares the running kernel version (`uname -r`) and its own version with values stored in EFI variables.
- If the values in EFI are newer, boot is aborted.
- Otherwise, the values are written to the EFI variables.